# Installing Virtualbox guest additions on Ubuntu 14.04 From Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I have purchased a new ssd for my laptop Dell Xps 15 lx502 and I have installed Windows 7 on it. Then, I have installed virtualbox 4.0.36 and I have tried to install ubuntu 14.04 and guest additions several times, but it seems that i have problem with graphic card or something else. This is the output from installation proccess:

```
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
: not foundh: 4: ./deffiles:
: not foundh: 16: ./deffiles:
: not foundh: 23: ./deffiles:
: not foundh: 73: ./deffiles:
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following      module compilation fails then this could be the reason.

Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used

Installing the Window System drivers
Warning: unknow version of the X Window System installed. Not installing
X Window System drivers.
Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
Press Return to close this window...
```

After reboot, i cant resize both displays I have installed. Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to install linux headers and Compiler tools within the guest:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers
```